# How to set min and max on an input type accepting floating value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

There are plenty of examples showing how to set min and max with integers. I need to ensure the range of values can even be float. Below is how I'm setting the attributes **value and max** for the input type `refund_amount`. The problem here is that one can enter a value higher than max value set with Jquery.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("grand_total");
    var dst = document.getElementById("refund_amount");
    if (dst != "") {
        dst.setAttribute("value", src.textContent);
        dst.setAttribute("max", src.textContent);       
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td align="right" colspan="3">Enter Refund Amount</td>
  <td align="left" colspan="4"><input type="text" size="11" id="refund_amount" 
                 name="refund_amount" value='' min="" max="" required/></td>
</tr>
```

How do I ensure it never allows higher value than what max attribute holds?

Comment: make it <input type="number" />

Comment: `min` and `max` only apply to `type="number"` inputs - and even then they aren't reliable as a means of validation. For example they do not stop the user typing in a higher number than the `max` allows. If you need to validate a value within a range you will need to do it manually.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, could you please share an example showing how to do it manually?

Comment: *an example showing how to compare values* - `if (src.value > 99)`

Comment: @freedomn-m, thanks, for your solution to be implemented, I should have an event handler in place. Correct?

Comment: Yes. I'd suggest using `input` if you want it to work as the user types

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, you mean input type="number"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min` and `max` attributes only work on `type="number"` inputs. It's also worth noting that they are not reliable as a means of validation, as they do not prevent the user from typing in a number outside the bounds of the `min`/`max` settings.

To work around that you can manually validate the value and correct it to be within bounds by using a `change` event and the `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` functions. Try this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var src = document.getElementById("grand_total");
  var dst = document.getElementById("refund_amount");

  if (dst) {
    dst.value = dst.max = src.textContent;
  }
});

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let el = e.target;
    el.value = Math.min(Math.max(el.value, el.min), el.max);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Grand total</td>
    <td id="grand_total">25.68</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="3">Enter Refund Amount</td>
    <td align="left" colspan="4">
      <input type="number" step="1" min="11.11" id="refund_amount" name="refund_amount" value="" required />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Rory, I hope you are keeping well. I've a request for you. Could you please have a look at this post to see if you can suggest some solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910147/close-previously-opened-accordion-with-pure-javascript?noredirect=1#comment127070019_71910147